# Javascript Object Literal Pattern, Click function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a starter at coding and trying to build my first plugin.
The problem what i have at this moment is when i try to use my click function, it's not clicking (it i's showing nothing inside the console from the test method).

Here is my code

JS

```
;(function($){
    var exampleObject = {
        init: function() {
            this.cacheDom();
            this.bindEvents();
        },
        cacheDom: function() {
            this.$examplebox = $("#exampleoneid");
            this.$examplebutton = this.$examplebox.find("#button-example");
        },
        bindEvents: function() {
            this.$examplebutton.on('click', this.test.bind(this));
        },
        test: function() {
            console.log("hello");
        }       
    };
    exampleObject.init();
})(jQuery);
```

HTML

```
<div id="firstbox">
     <div id="exampleoneid">
         <input type="button" id="button-example">
     </div>
</div>
```

It's executing on the page after the id. 
Hopefully someone knows the problem/solution.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with this, but you haven't shown the HTML it applies so, so its hard to test. You should provide a [mcve]

Comment: When is this executing? Is it *before* the element with ID `button-example` is on the page?

Comment: Not finding something in the DOM via jQuery does not result in an error. If the element with that ID is not in the DOM when the code runs, then you'll get the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Oh, I have spotted an obvious error now, with an obvious error message in the Console. **Always read the error messages**. You named something `this.$examplebox` on one line and then tried to access it as `this.examplebox` on the next. Off-topic. Problem caused by typo.

Comment: No it's not a typo. Fixing the html for it.

Comment: It's executing on the page after the id.

Comment: Fixed it. I had to refer to the highest div.